# Get index of matched words using regular Expression

Tags: python-2.7

i need a code that search for part of word (AIR-*) which repeated  in string then return all its indexes

i tried below code but i stuck for which method i can use with re to get all matched word indexes

import re

def main():
    crt.Screen.Synchronous = True

```
crt.Screen.Send('show cdp neig '+ '\r')
JGR=crt.Screen.ReadString("#")
strtolist=JGR.split(" ")
king = []
for xxx in strtolist:
    if xxx != "":
        king.append(xxx)
    else:
        continue

crt.Dialog.MessageBox(str(king))
z=[]
q=[]
word = "AIR-.*\w"
listostr = " ".join(king)
search= re.finditer(word,listostr)
crt.Dialog.MessageBox(str(search))
for ind,AP in enumerate(king):
    if AP == word:
        m = ind-5
        z.append(AP[m])
        n = ind-6
        q.append(AP[n])
    else:
        continue
crt.Dialog.MessageBox(str(z))
crt.Dialog.MessageBox(str(q))

#x=re.findall(word,JGR)
#crt.Dialog.MessageBox(str(x))
```

main()

this is text that i search in it
Name1
                 Gig 0/20          1              S I   WS-C3750X Gig
Name2
                 Fas 2/2           33             T B I  AIR-CAP26 Gig 0
Name3
                 Fas 1/3           14             T B I  AIR-CAP15 Gig 0
Name4
                 Fas 0/1           13             T B I  AIR-LAP12 Gig 0
the result is if i found AIR-* word then from its index i can go to interface index(Gig 0/20,Fas 2/2.Fas 1/3.Fas 0/1) and add it to list

Comment: May I suggest you take a basic English class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution but need one enhancement that after i got index i need to search again for word fas before this index instead of use fixed index movement 
    word = "AIR-.*\w"

```
for ind,AP in enumerate(king):
    if re.search(word, AP):
        m = ind-5
        z.append(m)
        n = ind-6
        q.append(n)
    else:
        continue

for i in z:
    AP1.append(king[i])

for o in q:
    AP2.append(king[o])


for H in range (len(AP1)):
    fin.append(AP2[H] + AP1[H])
```